change Emmet abbreviation ".." from 'styleName' to 'className'
In reactJs, using the '..' in emmet abbreviation will transform
div..parent

to this
<div styleName={styles.parent}></div>

but does anyone know the abbreviation that uses className instead of styleName? there's no answer in the Emmet's cheatsheet as of now
Yes, '.' abbreviation would create a className but I want it to have the '{styles.##}' already on it

Option 1.  div.{styles.parent}
Option 2. div[class={styles.parent}]
Press tab, then you will get
<div className={styles.parent}></div>

